# Can you spot the typo in the code for this React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble with embedding video in my react app (a netflix clone).

Instead of the embedded video, I'm seeing a black video window and a && on the screen.

I believe the problem is in the code below:

```
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <div className="row__posters">
        {movies.map((movie) => (
          <img
            key={movie.id}
            onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
            className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row_posterLarge"}`}
            src={`${base_url}${
              isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
            }`}
            alt={movie.name}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      {trailerUrl} && <YouTube videoId={trailerUrl} opts={opts} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've attached a screencap of the error:[error screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab6OW.png)

...I tried removing the right curly brace from {trailerUrl}, but that produced a failure to compile message.

Thoughts?

Thanks for checking this out!

Comment: Move the brace after the YouTube element: `{trailerUrl && <YouTube videoId={trailerUrl} opts={opts} />}`

Comment: put `{!!trailerUrl && <YouTube videoId={trailerUrl} opts={opts} />}`

Comment: An IDE would help you catch these on your own.  There's plenty of free options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curly braces are just in the wrong place. I believe proper syntax for this is

```
{ trailerUrlb && <YouTube videoId={trailerUrl} opts={opts} />}
```